# Why is "LIMIT 0" even allowed in MySQL SELECT statements?

Tags: mysql, database

`Limit 0, 1000` returns the first 1,000 results, but `LIMIT 0` returns 0 results.

That's not very intuitive imho. For example, dumb old me thought that removing the 1000 would remove the upper limit to the SELECT query, thus returning all of the results.

Why would anybody even want to query MySQL for 0 results?

Comment: You don't have to specify a limit on a query, if you want all the rows just omit the LIMIT clause completely. (However, certain environments, such as MySQL Workbench, do have configurable limits to prevent accidentally selecting all the rows out of a multi-million row table.)

Comment: `select count(*) from mytable limit 0` is one such place where I've seen it used. of course, removing `limit 0` doesn't affect anything here, I guess it just TRIES to ensure no rows are returned whatsoever

Comment: I came here because, like you, I wondered if LIMIT 0 would remove the upper LIMIT. In my case I  have LIMIT as a parameter in a parametrized query and I was hoping that 0 for LIMIT would remove the upper LIMIT so that I could reuse the query in cases where I do not want a limit. Looks like either I can't reuse the query in this scenario or put a ridiculously high limit on it, though that feels  hacky.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

From the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/limit-optimization.html)

> LIMIT 0 quickly returns an empty set. This can be useful for checking the validity of a query. When using one of the MySQL APIs, it can also be employed for obtaining the types of the result columns.

Answer (score 1):

`limit 0` can be used to get the same columns types of other tables

```
create table newtable
select col1 from table1 limit 0;
```

That way, a hard-coded description of the columns types for `newtable` is not needed, ensuring that the columns types will still match even if a change occurs in the description of `table1` before creating `newtable`

It also works with a more complete statement, involving indexes, engine, multiple tables, etc

```
create table newtable (primary key (col1)) engine=memory
select col1,col2,col3 from table1,table2 limit 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

*Polite corrections are welcomed and appreciated if I am incorrect here, but:

My understanding is that LIMIT 0, 1000 is telling SQL that you want to start with the first set of 1000 results in a given database, for the given criteria. For example, if there are 10,000 resulting rows in a dataset, LIMIT 0, 1000 would show you the first set of 1000 results. The zero is like the index of an array in JavaScript - the code starts ITS count with zero, rather than one, when referencing an array item. So item #1 is actually item #0, item #2 is actually item #1, and so on.

Comment: That's true but it's only treated as an offset when there are two parameters.  When there is only one parameter, the parameter is treated as a number of rows.   However, @Brandon had a true answer for this question.

Comment: Your understanding is correct. But this doesn't really answer the question that was asked: **"Why would anybody even want to query MySQL for 0 results?"**.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers already given, it is also useful when you want to make operations to a table based on the number of rows present in that table.

I.e. using PHP, if you want to delete all entries except for the one with the greatest id from table "myTable":

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("hostname", "username", "password", "database"); // Connect
$totalRows = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable"); // Get total row count
$mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM myTable WHERE id >= 0 LIMIT ($totalRows - 1);"); // Delete
?>
```

It's really useful because if you already only have 1 row left, you'll be left with `LIMIT 0`, which is what you want.